# JwPlayer api inject "repeat" option

Tags: javascript, api, jwplayer

In jwplayer i have an external button "repeat"
I want to inject this option to the jwplayer without reload or pause the streaming file.

I know i can do it by this method:

```
jwplayer('player').setup({
        "file": 'file.mp3',
        "repeat": true,
    });
```

But if the user clicks "repeat button" when the player is playing some file, the player will be reloaded again also i have to provide the file name again.

So i want to inject the option "repeat" without affecting the played file and without reloading the player.

Also i want to know the current "repeat" status (true/flase) to make toggle button.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat is not available via the API at this time. It's part of the player setup config, and therefore can't be injected without reloading the player.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
I made a temporary solution which get the current time and save it in a variable then after reloading the jwplayer setup i use seek() to this time.